# Why is my Javascript view on a buffer all zeroes?

Tags: javascript

I create a buffer and then a Uint8Array on it, but the array does not have any values. I would expect it to have the values of the buffer. This is an easily reproducible example:

```js
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(32);
for (var index = 0; index < 32; index++) buf[index] = index;
console.log(buf);
var arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
console.log(arr);
```

The thing I tried in reality is a date format converter like this:

```
//Buffers and views
function convertDateTimeToFormat(date, initialFormat, endFormat) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(14);
    var result = new Uint8Array(buf);
    console.log(date);
    var initialPositions = {};
    var endPositions = {};
    var sizeSoFar = 0;
    for (var c of initialFormat) {
        if (c === 'y') {
            initialPositions.y = new Uint32Array(date, sizeSoFar, 1);
        } else {
            initialPositions[c] = new Uint8Array(date, sizeSoFar, 2);
        }
        sizeSoFar += ((c === 'y') ? 4 : 2);
    }
    sizeSoFar = 0;
    for (var c of endFormat) {
        if (c === 'y') {
            endPositions.y = new Uint32Array(buf, sizeSoFar, 1);
        } else {
            endPositions[c] = new Uint8Array(buf, sizeSoFar, 2);
        }
        sizeSoFar += ((c === 'y') ? 4 : 2);
    }
    for (var key in initialPositions) {
        var limit = (key === 'y') ? 4 : 2;
        for (var index = 0; index < limit; index++) endPositions[c][index] = initialPositions[c][index];
    }
    return result;
}
//2019-03-01 13:03:50
var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 14 );
buf[0] = 2;
buf[1] = 0;
buf[2] = 1;
buf[3] = 9;
buf[4] = 0;
buf[5] = 3;
buf[6] = 0;
buf[7] = 1;
buf[8] = 1;
buf[9] = 3;
buf[10] = 0;
buf[11] = 3
buf[12] = 5;
buf[13] = 0;
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "yMdHms", "yMdHms"));
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "yMdHms", "MdyHms"));
```

But due to the behavior I described at the start of this question, the results are all zeroes.

This works but it's not elegant, because it expects a date format and if I am to ensure that the input is agnostic to date formats, then the code will become very complicated:

```
//Buffers and views
var results = {};
var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 4 );
results.uint32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
results.int8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
results.uint8 = new Int8Array(buf);
results.int8[2] = -1;
console.log(results);
results.int8[2] = 0;
results.int8[1] = -1;
console.log(results);
results.int8[1] = 0;
results.int8[0] = -1;
console.log(results);

//Buffers and views
function convertDateTimeToFormat(date, format) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(14);
    var result = new Uint8Array(buf);
    var positions = {
        y: 0,
        M: 4,
        d: 6,
        H: 8,
        m: 10,
        s: 12
    };
    for (var index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
        result[index] = date[positions[format[index]]++];
    }
    return result.join("");
}
var results = {};
//2019-03-01 13:03:50
var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 14 );
buf[0] = 2;
buf[1] = 0;
buf[2] = 1;
buf[3] = 9;
buf[4] = 0;
buf[5] = 3;
buf[6] = 0;
buf[7] = 1;
buf[8] = 1;
buf[9] = 3;
buf[10] = 0;
buf[11] = 3
buf[12] = 5;
buf[13] = 0;
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "MMddyyyyHHmmss"));
```

Comment: Why are you even using a buffer instead of simple plain strings?

Comment: In your first example, when you `console.log(arr.buffer);`, you'll notice that `Uint8Array` actually did record the `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: I will have to do a presentation to the dev team I'm part of tomorrow about https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch5.md and studying the topic on that page, cooking up some examples.

Comment: @kemicofa I'm logging the buffer first and yes, it has the data, but when I create a view from it, it's all zeroes. The thing I do not understand is: why is my view (Uint8Array) not holding the values I assigned to the elements of the buffer. If I create a view before I assign the data it works, but I wonder whether I can create such views after assigning the data and having the assigned data inside it.

Comment: I think it's like what Bergi said that it's just a slice of memory and Uint8Array just doesn't have direct access to its contents. I wonder why in the mdn documentation they allow Uint8Array to be constructed with an ArrayBuffer if the values don't get copied. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @kemicofa that's precisely my problem. I know I can work around, for instance reading every byte from the buffer and populate my view, but I will have to keep an eye on the endianness as well and it's kind of defeating the purpose of having a typed array at all in my opinion. So, if there is a solution to automatically populate the Uint views from the buffer, then it would make sense to use typed arrays if one wants to have micro optimisations. If not, then I do not understand why do we have typed arrays at all.

Comment: @kemicofa by "automatic" I of course mean language-level instead of writing algorithms for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) is just an object representing a slice of memory. It has a fixed size, that's it. It does *not* have properties that represent the contents, for that you'll need a typed array as a view on the buffer. Your code is just assigning properties to the buffer which works as it is an object, but it doesn't actually manipulate the byte contents which stay zero.

Don't explicitly instantiate the buffer at all if you don't need it. Just write

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(32);
for (var index = 0; index < 32; index++) arr[index] = index;
console.log(arr.buffer); 
console.log(arr);
```

---

In your actual code, it seems you want to use an `Uint8Array` to store the numbers in individual bytes. And probably you should just pass that array instead of the underlying buffer into the function.

You can create it like this:

```
const arr = Uint8Array.of(2,0,1,9,0,3,0,1,1,3,0,3,5,0);
// or       Uint8Array.from([2,0,1,9,0,3,0,1,1,3,0,3,5,0])
// or       new Uint8Array(2,0,1,9,0,3,0,1,1,3,0,3,5,0]);
const buf = arr.buffer;
```

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but then why does the mdn documentation on [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) show that it can accept an `ArrayBuffer` if the contents don't get copied ?

Comment: Actually if I assign data after I create the view, it works, but if you view my other examples inside the question where I do not know the date format beforehands, you see a practical example I cooked up where it would be superior to be able to define a view after the buffer was populated with data.

Comment: @kemicofa It can accept an existing buffer on which it will become a view. (I'm not sure what you mean by "get copied"). But it can also create the buffer itself, which is often simpler.

Comment: @LajosArpad You can define other views after the buffer was populated, no problem. The point is that for initially populating it you will need to use a view as well.