# Why is converting date format slower with buffers than with String operations?

Tags: javascript, performance

Consider this code:

```
    //Buffers and views
    function convertDateTimeToFormat(date, format) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(14);
        var result = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var positions = {
            y: 0,
            M: 4,
            d: 6,
            H: 8,
            m: 10,
            s: 12
        };
        for (var index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
            result[index] = date[positions[format[index]]++];
        }
        return result;
    }
var dt = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var results = {};
    //2019-03-01 13:03:50
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 14 );
    buf[0] = 2;
    buf[1] = 0;
    buf[2] = 1;
    buf[3] = 9;
    buf[4] = 0;
    buf[5] = 3;
    buf[6] = 0;
    buf[7] = 1;
    buf[8] = 1;
    buf[9] = 3;
    buf[10] = 0;
    buf[11] = 3
    buf[12] = 5;
    buf[13] = 0;
    convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "MMddyyyyHHmmss");
}
var dt2 = new Date();
console.log(dt2 - dt);
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(buf, "MMddyyyyHHmmss"));
```

The times it takes in 10 experiments were:

> 200, 184, 195, 186, 197, 193, 198, 197, 211, 202

On average: **196.3**

I have tried this with String operations as well:

```
function convertDateTimeToFormat(date, format) {
    var result = "";
    var positions = {
        y: 0,
        M: 4,
        d: 6,
        H: 8,
        m: 10,
        s: 12
    };
    for (var index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
        result += date[positions[format[index]]++];
    }
    return result;
}
var dt = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i <100000; i++) {
    var source = "20190301130350";
    convertDateTimeToFormat(source, "MMddyyyyHHmmss");
}
var dt2 = new Date();
console.log(dt2 - dt);
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(source, "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
console.log(convertDateTimeToFormat(source, "MMddyyyyHHmmss"));
```

Yet, the times needed were:

> 70, 72, 61, 61, 65, 72, 60, 61, 72, 68

On average: **66.2**

My expectation was that the first script should be much quicker than the second, because String operations tend to be slow. Yet, it is the other way around. Why is the result diametrically opposite to my expectations?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a read at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24855023/2275797 which seems somewhat **related** to your issue.

Comment: Hard to say. Some guesses would be: The arrayBuffer method has to create 3 different arrayBuffers for each i, compared to only one string. Also, there's alot of optimalization going on inside the browser if a function is fully predictable in advance. Since strings are immutable in JS, I would expect that that can be optimized way better than buffers that contain arbitrary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests not measure the same as on the first test you are wasting time creating a new ArrayBuffer, and on the second test the string is "already defined in memory", so is way cheaper.

I've created a test with different date numbers (randomized), creating a buffer and a string for the same numbers BEFORE starting the timer. Strings are still faster, but less. This is the result:

[image]

```js
var SIZE = 100000;
var dates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(14);
    var str = "";
    buf[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[4] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[5] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[6] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[7] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[8] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[9] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[10] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[11] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[12] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    buf[13] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < 14; ii++) {
        str += buf[ii];
    }
    dates.push({buf, str});
}

function convertDateTimeToFormatBuf(date, format) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(14);
    var result = new Uint8Array(buf);
    var positions = {
        y: 0,
        M: 4,
        d: 6,
        H: 8,
        m: 10,
        s: 12
    };
    for (var index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
        result[index] = date[positions[format[index]]++];
    }
    return result;
}
function convertDateTimeToFormatStr(date, format) {
    var result = "";
    var positions = {
        y: 0,
        M: 4,
        d: 6,
        H: 8,
        m: 10,
        s: 12
    };
    for (var index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
        result += date[positions[format[index]]++];
    }
    return result;
}

console.time("Buffer");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    convertDateTimeToFormatBuf(dates[i].buf, "MMddyyyyHHmmss");
}
console.timeEnd("Buffer");

console.time("String");
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    convertDateTimeToFormatStr(dates[i].str, "MMddyyyyHHmmss");
}
console.timeEnd("String");
```

V8 is greatly optimized when concatenating strings. You have a fixed loop with a simple string concatenation, so V8 optimizes it pretty well as he knows what is actually happening inside the loop. I guess that the *string concatenation in memory* don't happens until the loop ends, which is going to be pretty fast.

With buffers things are different. You are not concatenating nothing, as you are simply accesing memory positions (although you do it sequentially), but expect here that on each position that you set, the memory write *happens instantly* (without any optimization). All this with the overhead that means writting to a uint8array.

Typed arrays suggests that memory is directly accessed, like happens in C and such, but in JavaScript typed arrays have way more overhead than a string, as you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45808835/1525495

Answer (score 1):

You are still [using `ArrayBuffer` wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926589/1048572). That `var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 14 );` is used the same as if you had written `var buf = {};` - you create properties on it as on any ordinary object, and that is slow.

Instead, you should do

```
var buf = [];
```

or

```
var buf = new Uint8Array(14);
```

---

That said:

> String operations tend to be slow.

No. String operations are heavily optimised by JS engines, even repeated `+=` operations in a loop. And strings are relatively cheap to create.

On the other hand, typed arrays and array buffers have quite some overhead at their creation. They may be fast to access, but your simple benchmark doesn't use them that much - only setting and reading and setting each of the 14 indices, but creating two `ArrayBuffer` and two `Uint8Array` instances.